# How to restrict user from accessing a particular page by typing the url using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to restrict page with url say "myurl/view". Only admin users can view this page and other users cannot access this page.

Currently when view button is clicked it redirects to url "/view". and this view button is visible only to admin users.

below is my code,

```
render = () => {
    const admin = //some logic here and this admin value is boolean;
    return (
        <>  
            {admin && <a href="/view">
                <button>View</button>
             }
        </>
    );
}
```

As seen from  above code this button is visible only to admins and clicking it will redirect to "/view".

now when user who is not admin types "/view" it gets him to the same page which he is not supposed to view.

how can i restrict this access using react router. i am doing this for the first time and not sure how to do this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redirect component from react-router-dom. [Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) is the documentation page. This is the example usage based upon your situation.

```
<Route exact path="/view">
  {isAdmin ? <AdminPage /> :<Redirect to="/" />}
</Route>
```

FYI, this is how you import it

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: so does this work for example user is in "/view" and then user is not admin will this still work. meaning in this case he should be redirected to home page

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're talking about the scenario in which the user in in "/view" route , initially, because he's been authorize and then suddenly , because his token expired, he's not authorized to view that page anymore; in that case if your `isAdmin` state is reliable, the user should be redirected back to homepage when the token is expired.

Answer (score 0):

store a jwt token and verify the token on backend and see if the token corrsponds to the connected account trying to access url. If token is owned by an admin, return admin page otherwise an error page appear.